# Accessing remotely extender attached to router

Tags: networking, router, remote-access, remote

When I'm accessing locally my office network, the router is http://192.168.1.1/. I can then login, discover the extender's IP, something like 192.168.1.xx and connect to the admin interface of the extender.

When I'm accessing remotely my office network, the router's IP is something like 37.147.xx.xx, that is, the external IP. However how could I reach my extender, when connecting remotely?

Answer (score 0):

The same way as you would access any other service running inside the LAN: "Port forwarding". Forward some random external port to 192.168.1.xx:80, and it will be accessible from outside.

Note: Using 80 as the external port will be a bad idea. Pick something random in the [10000, 65534] range instead.

(Alternatively, VPN into the home router, if it supports that.)

If the extender's IP address keeps changing, make it static – your router possibly has a "static DHCP lease" or "DHCP reservation" feature. That will allow port forwarding to work, and you won't need to re-"discover" the address every day.